# Как на команду старт в боте поставить счетчик и выводить значение счетчика через определенную команду?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Как в данный код вписать переменную, которая при нажатии на старт в боте увеличивалась на 1

И при вводе команды /stata в боте выводило значение переменной

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("текст"))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'текст', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь может быть 2 варианта

Переменная на сессию(при перезапуске бота обнуляется):

```
i = 0
...
def start(message):
 i = i + 1
 if message.text.lstrip('/').lower() == 'start':
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, str(i))
 ...
```

Или переменная, которая хранится вне программы(для примера возьмем JSON)

Пусть json файл будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
{
 "startcount":0
}
```

Тогда в программе мы можем сделать так

```
    import json
    
    with open('file.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    ...
    def start(message):
         data['startcount'] = data['startcount'] + 1
         with open('file.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
         if message.text.lstrip('/').lower() == 'start':
           bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, str(data['startcount']))
         ...
```